# Unable to get error response in error body of retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am unable to get 400 response in error body of retrofit. I have set logging level its showing in logs but not showing in error body i have searched a lot but didn't find any solution is anyone there who help me in this case to get rid of this problem

```
call_.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
               if (response?.code() == 400) {
                      var jObjError: JSONObject? = null
                      try {
                          var jObjErrorr = response.errorBody().string()
                          CustomLogs.displayLogs("$TAG jObjErrorr: $jObjErrorr")
                      } catch (e: Exception) {
                      }

                      try {
                          val string = jObjError?.getstring("error_description")

                          CustomLogs.displayLogs("$TAG jObjError: $string")

                      } catch (e: Exception) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                  }
 }
```

i need error body to get and display message and my log shows this

```
{"error":"Authorize","error_description":"Error in authentication"}
```

but error body is not showing this object

Comment: you should use `onFailure` method

Comment: its not going onFailure

Answer (score 3):

As IntelliJ Amiya mentioned in comment to your original post you should do this in `onFailure` method. As far as I know Retrofit's `onResponse` will not be called in cases of response code not in 200 range (200, 201, 202 etc.) so your check for `if (response?.code() == 400)` will never return true.

Comment: Just re-checked what onResponse is handling. and I was not right. Sorry for that. An HTTP response may still indicate an application-level failure such as a 404 or 500.

Comment: its returning true... its going onSuccess and giving 400 code

Comment: Just mentioned spell mistake: var jObjErrorr = response.errorBody().string() and you are calling jObjError?.getstring("error_description"). "jObjErrorr" and "jObjError". Isn't that your problem?

Comment: You are creating nullable jObjError var. And the in try-catch block you're getting errorbody to different object you're creating right there jObjErrorr. And then you're trying to get string from first object which is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to add it as separate answer:

```kotlin
if (response?.code() == 400) {
    var jObjError: JSONObject? = null
    try {
        jObjError = response.errorBody().string()
        CustomLogs.displayLogs("$TAG jObjError: $jObjError")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }

    try {
        val string = jObjError?.optString("error_description")

        CustomLogs.displayLogs("$TAG jObjError: $string")

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Could you try this fragment?

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the Retrofit onResponse Library...,it's clearly mentioned that Retrofit does not create Body for response with status code below 200 or above 300.You have to specify your error Response Specifically!!

Comment: Welcome!  It's preferred to include a link to the documentation and also to copy the relevant paragraph into your answer and format it as a quote.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in Kotlin:

```
val errorResponse: ErrorMessage? = Gson().fromJson(
                response.errorBody()!!.charStream(),
                object : TypeToken<ErrorMessage>() {}.type
            )
```